# Element not appeared xyz seconds inside Frame, robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to click a checkbox which is present inside a frame but i always end up with this error message(Element not appeared for xyz seconds). Can anyone please help out

My code is as follows:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Select Frame                           (Frame name)
    Wait Until Page Contains element       (locator with xpath)          10s
    Select Checkbox                        (locator with XPath)
    Unselect Frame
```

I even tried using
Wait until element is visible but its still the same error

Comment: Have you examined a screenshot and/or looked at the source code to see if the element is visible?  Are you certain the element is in the given frame and not in another frame?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes, I have checked it and the element is visible and given inside the frame